# Как получить информацию с бд

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

имеется функция, как сделать так, чтоб она возвратила значение запроса?

```
    public void getMyMoney() throws SQLException {
    open();

    String strSQL = "select SUM(operat_sum) as Costs from operations";
    database.execSQL(strSQL);

    close();
}
```

вот методы `open() & close`

```
public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

так изменил и вываливается ошибка `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

```
 public int getMyMoney2() throws SQLException {
    open();

    int myMoney = 0;

    String strSQL = "select SUM(operat_sum) as Costs from operations";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(strSQL, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("operat_sum");

        do {
            // получаем значения по номерам столбцов
            myMoney = c.getInt(idColIndex);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "COLUMN_OPERAT_SUM = " + c.getInt(idColIndex));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    close();

    return myMoney;
}
```

Comment: Нужно ```c.getColumnIndex("Costs")```

Comment: @temq, спасибо большое помогли, невнимательность

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно получить Cursor, курсор возращают query, rawQuery, должно получится, что-то похожее на это

```
public List<OurObject> getMyMoney() throws SQLException {
    open();

    List<OurObject> ourObjectList = new ArrayList<OurObject>();

    String strSQL = "select SUM(operat_sum) as Costs from operations";
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(strSQL, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {

        // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("email");

        do {
            // получаем значения по номерам столбцов
            OurObject ourObject = new OurObject();
            ourObject.id = c.getInt(idColIndex);
            ourObject.name = c.getInt(nameColIndex);
            ourObject.email = c.getInt(emailColIndex);

            ourObjectList.add(ourObject);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    close();

    return ourObjectList;
}
```

Comment: я немного изменил под себя ваш способ и вывалилась ошибка `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`